# Encrypt passwords in individual files

Tags: passwords, svn, truecrypt

I used to keep my passwords in individual files, this was easy and convient because I could set up for

```
pass.bat => @notepad c:\passwords\%1.txt
```

Also, they could sync over subversion because they were different size on change.

Now I have then in a true crypt volume which is annoying because instead of.

1. Win+R
2. pass sitename
3. copy password
4. close notepad

I have to

1. Win+R
2. passwords
3. double-click allpasswords2.tc
4. click Mount
5. type in password
6. wait for mount
7. Win+R
8. x:\
9. locate site file
10. open site file
11. copy password
12. close notepad
13. close explorer
14. click "Unmount All"
15. close truecrypt

In addition, I have to rename the truecrypt file every time i make a change becuase subversion is an idiot and syncs based on file size which is a terrible indicator of change.

Is there an easier way to do this because i am thinking about returning to plain text.

---

Alright, my question was apperently too generic.  Here's what I want:

- Encrypted text file**S**
- That change *size* to indicate the data within is changed.

Is that so hard?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked for a more specialised application? I mean one written specifically for storing passwords, rather than general encryption.

Eg. I believe I've heard good things about [KeePass](http://keepass.info). But if you google around, you'll find a lot of similar applications. You might find one which meets your particular needs better than TrueCrypt does.

Comment: Does not store in individual files.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [RoboForm2Go](http://www.roboform.com/pass2go.html).

1. Plug your USB flash drive with RoboForm2Go into any PC and log into any website, or fill any form, all with one click!

   - Remove your RoboForm2Go USB flash drive and no information will be left on the host PC.
   - [Security](http://www.roboform.com/features.html#security)

I like TrueCrypt more for file-encryption but continue to use it for some of my password files too.
Some [more alternatives](http://www.techmixer.com/free-password-manager-to-keep-your-password-safe/).

Comment: Not only does Roboform protect/remember passwords, but it saves time because it handles going to the webpage, filling the form, and submitting.

Comment: @aaronls, yes, that is why I suggested it after `KeePass` was already mentioned over `TrueCrypt` (which I really like).

Comment: I don't want a USB flash drive, I want subversion.

Comment: @Miff, you can use any portable manager (KeePass is nice, look at the link on the last line), place the database into svn and keep the portable handy (or put that in svn too)

Answer (score -1):

I like [Password Safe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/) (Windows) and [Password Gorilla](http://www.fpx.de/fp/Software/Gorilla/) (Linux/Mac). They use the same format, and on my dual-booting box I can read/write the same password file from either OS. That file can be backed up however you like.